# Some confusing about the interpretation of the (reduced) BCS hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-field-theory, superconductivity, second-quantization

I used the following book (up to some notation variations): Condensed Matter Field Theory written by Alexander Altland, Ben Simons (edition 2).
The BCS (reduced) hamiltonian has the following form:
\begin{align}
         \hat{H} &= \sum_{k, \: \sigma}\epsilon_{k} \hat{c}_{k\sigma}^\dagger\hat{c}_{k\sigma} + \frac{1}{\Omega}\sum_{k,k'}V_{k'-k} \hat{c}_{k'\uparrow}^\dagger \hat{c}_{-k'\downarrow}^\dagger \hat{c}_{-k\downarrow} \hat{c}_{k\uparrow}
        \end{align}
This is equation (6.14) on page 264. They say the following about the BCS hamiltonian: the Hamiltonian should be interpreted as an effective Hamiltonian describing the physics of a thin shell of states of width $\mathcal{O}(\omega_D)$centered around the Fermi surface.

On page 53, equation (2.21) they defined $\hat{c}$ and $\hat{c}^\dagger$ in the following way:
\begin{align}
         \hat{c}_{k\sigma}^\dagger = \begin{cases} 
                \hat{a}_{k\sigma}^\dagger &, |k| > k_F \\
                \hat{a}_{k\sigma} & ,\:|k| \leq k_F \\
                \end{cases}
        \end{align}
\begin{align}
    \hat{c}_{k\sigma} = \begin{cases} 
            \hat{a}_{k\sigma} &, |k| > k_F \\
            \hat{a}_{k\sigma}^\dagger & ,\:|k| \leq k_F \\
            \end{cases} 
    \end{align}
which treats a filled Fermi sea as the vacuum and where $\hat{a}_{k\sigma}$ and $\hat{a}_{k\sigma}^\dagger$ are the usual creation and annihilation operators "using" the real vacuum.

So my question is the following: why does the BCS hamiltonian also discribe states under the Fermi sea when the Fermi sea is treated as the vacuum?

Comment: I am pretty sure that $c$ in the Hamiltonian you wrote should just be electron annihilation operators (equivalent to $a$). Otherwise you get strange sign changes in the second term. See e.g. here: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiQwZid8frtAhWOAGMBHVOOAT8QFjAAegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fportal.ifi.unicamp.br%2Fimages%2Ffiles%2Fgraduacao%2Faulas-on-line%2Ffen-emerg%2Flecture_notes_BCS.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1j6zZm1xjIyi6RfmbaYcDD

Comment: What's below the Fermi sea can be considered as an antiparticle.

Comment: @YardenSheffer I thought this was correct because the trivial solution to the gap equation has is the normal metal. If you work this out it comes out as the vacuum for the c-operators, which is a Fermi sea (the normal state). If those are taken to be the normal a-operators the trivial solution comes out as the real vacuum and not the normal state (if I'm correct).